# extracting part of success text using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following text appearing on the success page of my application.

This is to confirm that your application has been received. Your Order Number is “#00007942”. If further instructions or any clarification is needed regarding your application, a representative will contact you.

Complete text having same property.

Please help me in extracting the value 00007942 and store it in variable.

Comment: specify the programming language to know the answer according to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get your text in your way.

```
String successMessage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector")).getText(); // use locator of your wish
```

Now, use replace all non-digit from your string as follows-

```
String orderNumber = successMessage.replaceAll("\\D+", ""); // this replaces all non-digits from your previous string
```

Answer (score 2):

**there is no way to retrieve partial text in selenium webdriver.**

Instead, you access the complete text of an Web Element using element.getText() in Java or element.text in python and store it as a String variable.

Then you process the string to retrieve the `substring` you want.

In all programming languages, there are many ways to achieve it. some of them are substring method, regular expression.